# Custom function to map two arrays of which one is subset to check if those exist

Tags: php, arrays, json, performance, coding-style

> ***Note:** To the downvoter and to those who need further clarification...*
>
> I am trying to get to a solution, to not walk through the loop. i.e., I don't wanna use `foreach` function.

Sorry about the crazy title. What I am trying to achieve is, I have two arrays, say:

```
$full = array("Apple", "Orange", "Mango", "Guava", "Tomato");
$user = array("Apple", "Orange", "Tomato");
```

I get this as JSON and I use `json_decode()` to convert it to array from JSON. Now my question is, I want to use this input to my function, that returns me something like this:

```
$userSelection = array(
    "Apple" => true,
    "Orange" => true,
    "Mango" => false,
    "Guava" => false,
    "Tomato" => true
);
```

For this, I could do something like:

```
function userSelection ($full, $user)
{
    $final = array();
    foreach ($full as $fruit)
        if (in_array($fruit, $user))
            $final[$fruit] = true;
        else
            $final[$fruit] = false;
    return $final;
}
```

To compress a few bits, I used this.

```
function userSelection ($full, $user)
{
    $final = array();
    foreach ($full as $fruit)
        $final[$fruit] = in_array($fruit, $user);
    return $final;
}
```

My question is, is there any other better way of doing this?

Comment: For what are you looking? Like a one line solution?

Comment: You cannot compress more than what you did in the compressed function...

Comment: I am not sure why I have been downvoted. Not exactly a one line answer, but something without the use of `foreach`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're interested in performance analysis: foreach() is O(N) (hit each element in $full), and in_array is also O(N) (look at each value in $user), so that loop is a worst-case O(N^2) operation. If you have lots of fruits, that is a performance bottleneck.

You could reduce this by turning $full itself into an associative array:

```
$full = array("Apple" => false
      , "Orange" => false
      , "Mango" => false
      , "Guava" => false
      , "Tomato" => false);
```

Then userSelection becomes:

```
function userSelection ($full, $user)
{
    // $full is passed by value (ie copied)
    foreach ($user as $fruit) {
        // check to avoid fruit injection attacks
        if (array_key_exists($fruit, $full))
            { $full[$fruit] = true; }
    return $full;
}
```

array_key_exists should be either O(log N) or O(1), depending on PHP's implementation, while the for loop remains O(N), for a worst-case O(N*log N) performance.

Of course you'll need a *lot* of fruit options to see any performance benefits.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) to find what elements from $user are in $full and/or [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) or what elements from $full are not in $user

Comment: I know this. Okay, then?